# echo incorrectly interpreting colors

Tags: bash, echo

I want my terminal prompt to change color depending on success of the previous command. Currently I achieve this with the following script:

```
exitstatus()
{
    if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then
        echo -e "\e[38;5;45mबरें"
    else
        echo -e "\e[38;5;211mचूक"
    fi
}
PS1="\[\e[38;5;252m\][\[\e[38;5;214m\]\A \$(exitstatus)\[\e[38;5;252m\]]> \[\e[0m\]"
```

Problem here is that echo inside exitstatus doesn't escape colors correctly, leaving some invisible characters. That causes my terminal to cut line short and write the new one on top of the previous when I type long commands.
[image]

With PS1 variable I solved this issue by adding `\[\]` around `\e[...m`. Echo, however, doesn't have square brackets as escape characters and I can't find a way to make it escape colors correctly.

Comment: Can you show us how this fails? I just tried your code on my machine and it seems to be working as expected. You probably want to use `printf` instead of `echo`, but that is always true and not specific to your issue. See [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803).

Comment: @terdon added an illustration.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. What happens if you try with a new user?

Comment: @terdon Same. printf doesn't seem to help either.

Comment: Better use [liquidprompt](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=liquidprompt)

Comment: @GillesQuenot Looks great. I'll definitely try it out.